# set raddatetimepicker date & time using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, telerik, datetimepicker

I have one raddatetimepicker in my page.
I am getting one date as string like this in javascript "2014-06-03T23-00-00Z"

I want to set this date to my raddatetimepicker.

I tried using this
[Set the date to raddatepicker by using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357272/set-the-date-to-raddatepicker-by-using-javascript)

But it is not working.

I also tried like this

```
var myDate = "2014-06-03T23-00-00Z";
var cdate = myDate.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');
$find("<%= fromDate.ClientID %>").set_selectedDate(dt);
```

Comment: I hope my answer helped.  Is this Telerik for ASP.NET or MVC?  You should tag the question accordingly to help people find this.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `set_selectedDate` accepts a [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Try the example below that also converts your current format to the valid Date object:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setDate() {
            var dt = "2014-06-20T23-00-00Z";
            dt = dt.replace('T', '-').replace('Z', '');
            var ar = dt.split('-');
            var rdtp1 = $find('<%= rdtp1.ClientID %>');
            rdtp1.set_selectedDate(new Date(ar[0], ar[1]-1, ar[2], ar[3], ar[4], ar[5]));
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

<telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtp1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadDateTimePicker>

<asp:Button ID="btnR" runat="server" OnClientClick="setDate(); return false;" />
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js) for more info on converting strings to the Date object in JavaScript.